# SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString) --> Invalid keyword : port

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, connection-string

Hi I try to add signalR my project for notifications.

I get error at Global.asax.cs.

When try to execute this SqlDependency.Start() I get error invalid keyword : port,I'm using postgresql for database and connectionstring have port I think that's why I get error but how can I start sqldependency while using postgresql.

Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings><add name="connectStr" connectionString="server=localhost;port=5432;database=wfs_db;user id=postgres;password=1" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
```

Global.asax.cs

```
 var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectStr"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString); 

        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);//get error here
```

I tried this:

```
connectionString="server=localhost:5432;database=wfs_db;user id=postgres;password=1" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

but could not connect to database

please help.

Comment: And like always in those cases: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ - all coinnection strings explained with all parameters. YOu do realize that "Port" may not be the same as "port"? Also maybe you do not set up a postgres conection. IS thre a SqlDependency for Postgres? The one I know is only SQL Server.

Comment: so do  i couldn't use sqldependency with postgre ?

Comment: I do not know. I do not use postgres. The documentation, though (which I think you should read at some point) indicates it is a sql server feature.